# How do I stop Java program arguments being mistaken for VM arguments?

Tags: java, batch-file

Inside a bat file I have the following:

`java -Ddatabase.host=127.0.0.1 -Xms128M -Xmx1024M com.temp.util.manual.serial.Assignment -folder C:\temp\ -destination C:\temp\out.csv`

The `-folder` and `-destination` params are supposed to be passed to the main method of the Assignment class being called, but instead they are being interpreted as VM Args.

I tried putting quotes around the params to no avail, and searching does not reveal an answer.

I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized option: -'destination'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Press any key to continue . . .

@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions 
set FILETYPE=%~n0
set CLASSPATH=jar1.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;anotherjar.jar
echo %CLASSPATH%
java -DjobName=%FILETYPE% -Ddatabase.host=127.0.0.1 -Ddatabase.name=db1 -Ddatabase.username=user1 -Ddatabase.password=password1 -Xms128M -Xmx1024M com.temp.util.manual.serial.Assignment -folder C:\\temp\\ -destination C:\\temp\\out.csv
call Cleanup.bat
endlocal
```

Comment: I notice you aren't specifying a class-path. Are your arguments in exactly that order?

Comment: I established the class-path prior to the line given.

Yes, arguments are in that order.

Comment: Show us your batch file. You're hiding something...

Comment: What is the result of `java -version`?

Comment: edited original post to include full bat

Comment: Why are you doubling the backslashes?  This isn't Linux, you don't need to escape backslash characters in Windows batch files.

Comment: Running your batch code I get **"Error: Could not find or load main class com.temp.util.manual.serial.Assignment"** - understandably because I don't have your jar, but your error is not reproducible.

Comment: pls check the bat file I added. Don't put code into comments.

Comment: I tried replacing `com.temp.util.manual.serial.Assignment` with a test class I do have (and put in jar1.jar), and I do not get an error.  The path names (doubled backslash and all) show up in the arguments to `main` as expected.

Comment: java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: @ajb 's comment appears to indicate that class com.temp.util.manual.serial.Assignment isn't in the jars or isn't a main class.

Comment: @laune Not so sure; izca's earlier comment indicates that if the class isn't in the jars then the result is a "could not find" error.  I haven't tried it with an existing class that isn't a main class, though.  Worth a try... naah, I get "Main method not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue has more to do with passing in variables.
Remove **EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions**

Comment: This works. So I thought I needed "EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions" because in Cleanup.bat I was using "echo !FILETYPE!" and that was failing but changing it to "echo %FILETYPE%" and removing "EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions" will get the java to work and all of my variables to print appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The command `java` has the following syntax:

```
java [ options ] class [ arguments ]
java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]
```

So in your case (class) it seems the class was not found. Probably due to missing class path.

```
java -cp . ... com.temp.util.manual.serial.Assignment ...
```

Maybe better not to rely on the CLASSPATH variable, use `-jar` and rely on a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: Why would it complain about an unrecognized option, instead of a class not being found?  I realize we can't do better than to take stabs at the issue, but this doesn't seem to explain the problem.

Comment: @ajb yes reading the comments it sounds a bit conspicuous. Maybe remove options, test and then start adding options. Even another main class would make sense.

Comment: If I remove "-DjobName=%FILETYPE% -Ddatabase.host=127.0.0.1 -Ddatabase.name=db1 -Ddatabase.username=user1 -Ddatabase.password=password1 " it will run the program even though it will bomb for other reasons.

Comment: @lucas.bennett Remove the first -Djon... or put it in quotes. Not sure what FILETYPE expands to.